# How to produce regex string to check to second word is uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I have two words within sentence.
EX: big BUTTON 
here I need to check second word is in uppercase using regex expression.

Comment: You need to show what you've tried, and what unexpected result you got.

Comment: Why do you need to use a regular expression? Are there always exactly two words in the sentence? What is your definition of upper-case? Should it match Cyrillic uppercase, or uppercase versions of two-byte versions of Roman letters?

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets `[]` are your friend. They allow you to specify characters that will match. To match the first work, you need to check for any letter. This can be done with `[a-zA-Z]`. This will match any letter between a and z, as well as A and Z. for the second word, you only want to match uppercase, so only use `[A-Z]`. To get 1 or more matches, put a `+` after the closing bracket.

Putting this all together, with a space in between the words, you get `[a-zA-Z]+ [A-Z]+`.

The carat `^` is used to signify the start of the string, and the dollar sign `$` is used to signify the end of the string. Your question somewhat vague, so here are a couple scenarios:

1. Each sentence is only two words with a space in between them: `^[a-zA-Z]+ [A-Z]+$`
2. Each sentence has at least two words and may or may not end in a period: `^[a-zA-Z]+ [A-Z]+( |\.?$)`

In the second example the parenthesis with a pipe `(|)` is used as an OR statement. The period is escaped since it is a special character (matches any single character). The question mark denotes 0 or 1 of the preceding character, which is a period. So `( |\.?$)` will match a space or a sentence that ends with or without a period.

Here is a good site that has information on Regexes: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Your solution would incorrectly match `first second THIRD` and `first Second third`, etc

Comment: But I got success even I give this one,   big Button. Actually here I need second word to be fully in CAPITAL

Comment: Thank you Mr.Sylvetrix. It was really help me.

Answer (score 0):

This regexp looks for any sequence, starting at the beginning of the string (`^`), of alphanumeric characters (`\w`)--that's the first word--then a space, followed by a sequence of upper-case letters (`[A-Z]+`)--the second word--followed by either a space or the end of the string (`$`).

```
/^\w+ [A-Z]+( |$)/
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.torazaburo. It was really help me.